# Combine more than 3 data.frames while keeping the extra-rows from the master file that didn't match

Tags: r, outer-join, rbind

I have the following data.frame "A" in R:

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 456 |
| 200 |
| 550 |
| 110 |

and the following data.frame "B" defined in R

| ID | Interaction | Student | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | email_sent | Isabel Gauss | 10/20/2021 |
| 200 | email_sent | Jason Bin | 2/8/2021 |
| 550 | email_sent | Brad Pit | 10/20/2021 |
| 999 | email_sent | John Brad | 10/15/2023 |
| 255 | email_sent | Joe Sam | 10/20/2021 |

and the following data.frame "C" defined in R

| ID | Interaction | Student | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Event_attend | Isabel Gauss | 09/14/2021 |
| 200 | Event_attend | Jason Bin | 6/9/2021 |
| 550 | Event_attend | Brad Pit | 10/20/2023 |
| 999 | Event_attend | John Brad | 10/10/2022 |
| 255 | Event_attend | Joe Sam | 10/15/2021 |

I need to have the following output ordered by ID:

| ID | Event_sent | Date_email | Email_attend | Date_attended |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Y | 10/20/2021 | Y | 09/14/2021 |
| 456 | N | Null | N | Null |
| 200 | Y | 2/8/2021 | Y | 6/9/2021 |
| 550 | Y | 10/20/2021 | Y | 10/20/2023 |
| 110 | N | Null | N | Null |

The following is not working properly:

```
merge <- merge(A, B, C, by.x = "ID", all.x = TRUE, sort = TRUE)
```

Comment: It's more helpful to provide code that makes the dataframes (e.g. by running `dput(A)` and pasting the result into your question), instead of showing what the dataframe prints out as, which is ambiguous as to data types and structure (e.g. grouping, nesting, etc.)

Comment: you mean run dput(x, filename, etc..) in my R code ?

Comment: If you have object `A`, you can run `dput(A)` and the output will be a code recipe to recreate the object. `dput(head(A))` would recreate the first 6 rows. `dput(A[1:5, 1:8])` would recreate the first 5 rows and the first 8 columns.

Comment: I would do something like `library(dplyr); bind_rows(left_join(A,B), left_join(A,C)) %>% tidyr::pivot(names_from = Interaction, values_from = Date)` with another step to add the Y/N.

Answer (score 0):

One approach, using a pipeline of {dplyr} and {tidyr} manipulations:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) ## for pivoting

A |>
  full_join(
    bind_rows(B, C) |>
    pivot_wider(names_from = Interaction, values_from = Date) |>
    rename(Date_email = email_sent,
           Date_attended = Event_attend
           )
  ) |>
  mutate(Event_sent = ifelse(is.na(Date_email), 'N', 'Y'),
         Email_attend = ifelse(is.na(Date_attended), 'N', 'Y')
         ) |>
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ ifelse(is.na(.x), 'Null', .x))) |>
  select(ID, Event_sent, Date_email, Email_attend, Date_attended) |>
  arrange(ID)
```

```
   ID Event_sent Date_email Email_attend Date_attended
1   1          Y 10/20/2021            Y    09/14/2021
2 110          N       Null            N          Null
3 200          Y   2/8/2021            Y      6/9/2021
4 255          Y 10/20/2021            Y    10/15/2021
5 456          N       Null            N          Null
6 550          Y 10/20/2021            Y    10/20/2023
7 999          Y 10/15/2023            Y    10/10/2022
```

(To learn which does which in the pipeline you can start with a large part of the downstream instructions commented out and inspect the intermediate results, then stepwise uncomment the rest of the pipe)